# jTable jQuery - Change delete icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

Is there any way to change delete icon in inbuilt jquery list? I tried searching in documentation but not able to find.

I have list and sublist in jtable and want to change subgrid delete icon to another icon.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague... Can you please explain, or maybe a jsfiddle should be of immense help ...

Comment: In jtable jquery grid. As example: jtable.org is site which lists grid. I want custom image of delete in place of existing one and am not able to find any way to do so. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete icon in jTable (jQuery, not java) is set with CSS. See for example the jtable_basic.css file which is containing the following lines:

```
div.jtable-main-container table.jtable tbody > tr > td .jtable-delete-command-button {
  background: url('delete.png') no-repeat;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
}
```

So change the background in the css file you use for your jTable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I sometime use my own delete column that calls a JavaScript function delete. I can also use any image src I want, or I could use a button as well.

```
delete:{
   width: '.5%',
   display: function(data){
        return '<img src="..." onClick="delete(' + data.record.id + ')/>';
   }
}
```